# Overriding parameter types?

Tags: oop, dart

I would like to override the parameter type of a method in its subclasses, I thought generics could be used for this but that does not seem to work (at least not the way I am doing it).

```
abstract class A {
 bool someMethod<T>(T x); 
}
```

Then override it like so:

```
class B extends A {
  bool someMethod<bool>(bool x) {
    // error: isn't a valid override
  }
}
```

I have had to default to using type `dynamic x` for the parameter type, but that forfeits runtime safety checks and means a lot of type checking whenever the method is implemented.

Is this type of extension possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but not the way you do it.
What you declare is a generic method, where each invocation gets to pass the type argument to the function.

What you probably want is:

```dart
abstract class A<T> {
  bool someMethod(T x); 
}

class B extends A<bool> {
  bool someMethod(bool x) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

That makes the type a parameter of the subclass, not the method, so each *subclass* can define its own type.

(Here you get into problems with Dart's covariant generics, because you can write:

```dart
A<Object> a = B();
a.someMethod("a"); // run-time error.
```

Your type variable occurs only in places where a value of that type is needed, not where one is provided, so casting to the superclass `A<Object>` make the method more permissive than it can support. The compiler inserts a run-time type check on the argument, which is what the example code here hits.)